# HTML code of component doesn't work in angular2

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, angular2-directives, angular-components

I am actually building my first angular app, and when i create a component like a Menu for example, I copy paste the html code of the menu from material.angular.io,and then i include the menu component in the root component, but all i get displayed is "Menu works!". Please what deoes it mean and how can I solve this problem. Thank you very much :)

here is my code :

menu.component.html file :

```
 <button md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
 <md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
   <button md-menu-item>Item 1</button>
   <button md-menu-item>Item 2</button>
 </md-menu>
```

menu.component.ts file :

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-menu',
   templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css']
 })
 export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor() { }

   ngOnInit() {
 }

}
```

app.component.html file :

```
 <app-menu></app-menu>
```

app.component.html file :

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })
 export class AppComponent {
   title = 'app works';
 }
```

app.module.ts :

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

 import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

 import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
 import {NoopAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
 import {MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';

 import 'hammerjs';
 import { NavBarComponent } from './components/nav-bar/nav-bar.component';
 import { SidenavComponent } from './components/sidenav/sidenav.component';
 import { MenuComponent } from './components/menu/menu.component';

 @NgModule({
   declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavBarComponent,
    SidenavComponent,
    MenuComponent,


  ],
 imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  NoopAnimationsModule,
  MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
 export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: reproduce it here: https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Yes, it is, your app works fine, that is everything your app is playing.

Comment: If you want to see you "title" in page, change app.component.html to : <app-menu></app-menu> <div>{{title}}</div>   to see.

Comment: i did, it shows "menu works !" then the title whitch is "app works" :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You MUST include MdMenuModule or MaterialModule for everything of angular2 material.

So use the app.module.ts as I posted above.

2) You used 3rd party plugin, I don't have them and removed them, so just modified your menu.component.html as:

```
<button md-button >Menu</button>
  <md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
    <button md-menu-item>Item 1</button>
    <button md-menu-item>Item 2</button>
  </md-menu>
```

teset

Everything works as expected.
Please note, I removed  [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu" and NavBarComponent,
SidenavComponent, because I don't have them.

Comment: Thank you very much Blockchain Nerd for your help, I restarted my server and I did what you asked me to do , and it works !

Comment: Hey there @BlockchainNerd, they will be removing `MaterialModule` in a subsequent release after `2.0.0-beta.10`, so you must import the modules you would like to use individually or by putting them in an array.

Answer (score 0):

So just try this App.Module.ts:

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

 import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

 import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
 import {NoopAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
 import {MaterialModule} from '@angular/material';

 import 'hammerjs';
 import { NavBarComponent } from './components/nav-bar/nav-bar.component';
 import { SidenavComponent } from './components/sidenav/sidenav.component';
 import { MenuComponent } from './components/menu/menu.component';

 @NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      NavBarComponent,
      SidenavComponent,
      MenuComponent,
      ],
 imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     BrowserAnimationsModule,
     NoopAnimationsModule,
     MaterialModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Yes, you MUST import MdMenuModule or MaterialModule as I shown in the above app.module.ts.   when I changed your menu.component.html as :<button md-button >Menu</button>
<md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
  <button md-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button md-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</md-menu>

<div>teset </div>

everything is fine.

Comment: Hey there @BlockchainNerd, they will be removing `MaterialModule` in a subsequent release after `2.0.0-beta.10`, so you must import the modules you would like to use individually or by putting them in an array.